# Add multiple parameters in drools action rules xlsx file

Tags: java, excel, drools

I everybody, like title explains , i have some troubles trying to creating xlsx file using drools rules.
In the specifics I create a table with a condition, but in the action sections I need to add multiple parameters (one is an Array of Enum elements and the second is another Enum element) like for example:

(Enum1.one,Enum1.two),Enum2.one

in the action section I write this rule importing Arrays library:

$fact.someMethod(Arrays.asList($1),$2)

but running a test it seems it doesn't see second parameters and it shows me an error like :

"The method somMethod( List, Enum2) in the type Fact is not applicable for the arguments (List)"

what i'm doing wrong? below i'm posting an example section of the excel file.
thank you all for your time.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case Drools parser is a little "confused" by the syntax, break it into multiple Action columns:

- make the list in its own (prior) column and assign it to a local variable (e.g. $theList)
- change the current (subsequent) column to use it: $fact.someMethod($theList, $1)

Comment: thank you man. assigning to a local variable worked :)